# SSH Multi-Hop VPN

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, vpn, tunnel

I have a few public servers and am attempting to tunnel through them for a Multi-Hop VPN project. The end goal is to set up multiple VPNs and forward all traffic (other than the needed SSH VPN traffic obviously) through them.

Basically I run "ssh -f -w 1:1 1.1.1.2 1.1.1.1 true" then setup the tunnel interfaces on both sides. Then set a static route so the tunnel stays up then forward the rest of the traffic through the tunnel (it gets MASQUERADEd to the front facing interface).

All good with one hop... added a second hop. It is not nested but rather another tunnel from my 1st hop to the second hop. I set up the routing and again, everything is all good. I can ping my 3rd public server and the ping takes the dual-tunnel path and pings the server via my last hop's public address. I can also connect to a website through the tunnel.

The problem is as soon as I then attempt to ssh to the same IP that I just pinged... the second tunnel breaks.

Comment: I am guessing it has something to do with key fingerprints needed somewhere but am never prompted on the host. I went through all of the hosts and ssh'd around to get accepted keys everywhere but no change.

Comment: Also went to every device involved and set "StrictHostKeyChecking no" in the ssh_config file with same results... maybe it has nothing to do with that but all other types of traffic seem to function with the exception of SSH to either any external IP or the tunnel address of the last hop.